# how to make titleBar of Flash mx.containers.Panel invisible?

Tags: apache-flex, flash

in FlashBuilder 4 beta 2, I've subclassed **mx.containers.Panel**, adding a public method to hide the titleBar:

```
    public function hideTitleBar(): void {

        if (null != this.titleBar){
            this.titleBar.visible=false;
        }
    }
```

I step through the code and see that the method is being invoked and that titleBar exists, and then step through the UIComponent classes and that all looks ok too: the component is initialized and $visible is being set to false.  Yet the gray bar across the top of the panel remains.  I want to eliminate that bar and would be grateful for some tips on how to do that.

Comment: I would start using Flex 4 :), much easier to do this stuff

Answer (score 4):

What I ended up doing is to set the style `headerHeight` to 0

```
this.setStyle("headerHeight", 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `updateDisplayList` method of the `Panel` sets `titleBar.visible` to `true`. Subclass the `Panel` class, override that method, and set it to `false` inside that. Don't forget to call `super.updateDisplayList`

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number,
                                              unscaledHeight:Number):void
{
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    titleBar.visible = true;
}
```